# how to stream multiple CameraBridgeViewBase in android, using android-openCV?

Tags: android, opencv

I am using openCV android and want to use 3 CameraBridgeViewBase but I am getting only one working how to set more than 1 CameraBridgeViewBase in android?

**Source code in on [Github](https://github.com/sejpalsinh/opencv_multi_show)**

**android app Screenshot only right side's view is working remaining  2 is not working how to solve??**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually not possible.

Because Any device have only one camera input so you can use that camera stream in to only on **CameraBridgeViewBase**

And still you want to do this for 3 camera view you can just copy one stream into variable and create 2 only View for that stream and set that variable value in remaining 2 View.